# When a question converts to community wiki, what rules wiki the answers?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038331) which was changed by someone to community wiki. Strangely, not all of the answers were changed to wiki as well. The question never reached the 30 answer auto-wiki limit. Also time doesn't seem to be related as there is a mix of owned answers and wiki answers.

Any ideas on what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question is converted to CW existing answers aren't. It will be up to the owners of the answers to go back and change the state.

New answers will be CW.

Or at least that's what I assume is happening from observation of the times it's happened to me.

Comment: Odd - I don't see a CW check box at all. I'm using Chrome at the moment (if that matters).

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: that's how it used to work. Now, you don't get the checkbox once the question is CW. So while existing answers are left un-CW until the 30-answer threshold is reached, new answers are always CW (well, ok, those started prior to the CWification can also be posted as non-CW).

Comment: @Shog9 - phew - I thought I was going crazy. I'd even got as far as opening up a CW question in Chrome and Firefox and taking screenshots!

Comment: @Shog9: You're right! When did that change? It must have been fairly recently. In any case, I've deleted my erroneous comment. Thanks for calling me out on that.

Answer (score 0):

There is one case in which SO behaves strangely.

If:

1. A question is asked as non-wiki
2. Less than 30 answers are posted
3. The question is converted to wiki by the asker
4. The question hits 30 answers

... then the answers posted before the wiki-ing of the question are never auto-converted to wiki.

If step 3 hadn't occurred, all answers would have been wikied.
If step 3 had been part of step 1 (i.e. the question had been originally asked as wiki), then all answers would have been wiki from the start.
But if step 3 occurs, then all answers posted before it occurs will never be wikified.

Here's an example: [What is your longest-held programming assumption that turned out to be incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888224/what-is-your-longest-held-programming-assumption-that-turned-out-to-be-incorrect)
If you scroll down, you'll see that even though there are more than 150 answers, some of the ones on the front page are not wiki.

Comment: I think this is what happened to my question, although I never changed it to wiki (perhaps a moderator did)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888224/what-is-your-longest-held-programming-assumption-that-turned-out-to-be-incorrect/888240#888240